Extension of C1 functions
I studying the extension problem for classes of function $C^0,C^1,D^1$ ($D^1=$class of derivable function).
For $C^0$ function there is Tietze theorem and for $D^1$ function there is Jarnik theorem (rediscovered by G. Petruska and M.Laczkovich-https://math.wvu.edu/~kciesiel/prepF/129.DifferentiableExtensionThm/129.DifferentiableExtensionThm.pdf).
I pose attention on $C^1$ functions.
I know that: exists a function $f\in C^1(X)$ on a perfect set $X ⊂ \mathbb{R}$ with no has extension $F \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$.
I'm looking for a necessary and sufficient condition for existence of a extension of $f\in C^1(X)$ where $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is perfect.
I have found a very general Whitney's theorem that i want adapte to monodimensional case.
I ask: it's true that $f\in C^1(X)$ is extendible to $F\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ iff  $\forall \varepsilon>0$ $\exists\delta>0$ t.c. $\lvert  f(x)-f(y)-f'(y)(x-y)\rvert<\varepsilon\lvert  x-y\rvert$ $\forall x,y\in P$ ,$\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta$ ?
Is this correct? Can someone kindly show me a reference or an idea of ​​the proof (aslike Jarnik?) of this property?

I don't have time to look into this now, but if you don't know the following papers by Jack B. Brown, then they might be helpful, at least with related results and references: $C^1$-intersection variant of Blumberg's theorem [Tatra Mountains Mathematical Publications 14 (1998), pp. 127−136] AND Restriction theorems in real analysis [Real Analysis Exchange
20 #2 (1994-1995), pp. 510−526].
